# How to increase zooming level of fs.zoomer jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want increase zooming level of fs zoomer jquery plugin i have tried a lot nothing happens

https://www.jqueryscript.net/zoom/Smooth-Image-Enlargement-Plugin-Zoomer.html

Comment: have you tried using a bigger picture ?

Comment: yes it still let me zoom 3 times click on zoomIn button (+) which is not enough zoom .